# pattern recognition in a time series

Tags: time-series, signal-processing, pattern-recognition

I understand that the question I am asking seem the be somewhat related to another question which has been asked already [here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/966/pattern-recognition-for-temporal-data) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11752727/pattern-recognition-in-time-series).

But I feel that this is an entirely different question. (I have also [submitted this question](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/19896/pattern-recognition-in-a-time-series) on the dsp.stackexchange)

I have a huge (over 100K data points) time series data of the position (x, y coordinates) of an element in space. This element is vibrating randomly, and both amplitude and the frequency of vibration is random. I want to look at the events which are similar and see if there is any pattern in those events, are they periodic or related somehow.

I am working on a biological problem and have very little knowledge about signal processing. I can provide more details. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: if you're looking for patterns of anomaly check this [article](https://blog.twitter.com/2015/introducing-practical-and-robust-anomaly-detection-in-a-time-series)

Comment: Thanks! but I am not looking for anomalies, in fact I do not know what I am looking for! I am trying to establish a pattern, and thus am fishing for one.

Comment: so there is no direct answer, you should proceed scientifically, check how people in the same field used to process these data (e.g. visualization first)

Comment: I was wondering if I can find a way where I can plot for each type of vibration event (amplitude and frequency is comparable) separately? If this makes any sense?

Comment: I suggest that you will define more clearly what do you mean by an "event" in your problem. Is that a single instance of the time series? a sequence of a fixed length? a sequence of variable length? A sequence where there is a non-negligible change of position?

Comment: Another thing is what exactly do you mean by your data being random, in respect to your desire to look for patterns in it. The very definition of randomness is the absence of a pattern between different data instances.

Answer (score 0):

One of the areas of the research on time series patterns is called Motif Detection or Discovey, some use association strategies, other are probabilistic.

Some links here [http://dl.acm.org/results.cfm?query=motif+discovery&Go.x=5&Go.y=12](http://dl.acm.org/results.cfm?query=motif%20discovery&Go.x=5&Go.y=12)