# Pattern recognition in time series using LSTM(python)

Tags: python, machine-learning, time-series, pattern-recognition, recurrent-neural-network

My application scenario is similar to the previous one [Pattern recognition in time series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11752727/pattern-recognition-in-time-series)

By processing a time series dataset, I Would like to detect patterns that look similar to this:
[image]
Using a sample time series as an example, I would like to be able to detect the patterns as marked here:
[image]

But I want to do it with **python and LSTM**.

I have read some resouces about the RNN time series and word classification.I know how RNN predicts results in time series, but I'm puzzled how to find a pattern in time series.

I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this.

Since I am not a native English speaker, if there is anything I didn't describe clearly, please ask.Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You may refer to this nice tutorial : https://github.com/guillaume-chevalier/seq2seq-signal-prediction

It can find pattern of sinewave and generate future values.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.But after I read the "Readme.md",I could't find which exercise is used to find a pattern in time series.I have known how to predict the future values.

Comment: Could you tell me which exercise can find pattern of signals directly or by modifying its code appropriately.

Comment: @Neil Han                                                                                                   I looked at your answer to the question "[Pattern recognition in time series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11752727/pattern-recognition-in-time-series)", I think it's very useful, can you please tell me  how the LSTM is used for pattern recognition?

Comment: Hello @yingxing.bao! Did you find the answer to your question? I have the same task now. Could you give me a few recommendations?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't done this work since then, but you can look at some algorithms like dynamic time warping. That might be useful.